# is there `from <module> import <class>` syntax in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6 importing goes for example:

`import MyClass from "module";`

The problem is intellisense doesnt pick up like in python. In python it would be for example:

`from mo` and here intellisense would already start working and would offer to complete `module`

`from module import M` and here would already offer all the classes starting with M.

Instead of `import Class from module` is there a way to do
`from module import Class` in ES6?

Comment: No, the syntax is what it is. JavaScript statements generally are introduced by a keyword, and `import` follows that pattern.

Comment: Start with `import {} from "module"`, then when filling in the brackets you should be able to get intellisense. (Of course the IDE could be more clever about this). But regarding default imports like `import MyClass from "module";`, no there cannot be any intellisense autocompletion, as you are responsible for choosing the local alias yourself.

Comment: Really don't understand why this was downvoted. It's a legitimate question, asked in a clear and concise way, that could be useful to other people.

Comment: @LionelRowe thank you

Comment: Have a look at [Typing import statements more quickly](https://2ality.com/2017/08/typing-import-statements.html) and [The Module Import in JavaScript Has a Drawback](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-import-module-drawback/) or [this TypeScript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2371) for workarounds

Answer (score 0):

It is dependent upon the IDE. I have found in VS Code that the method [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) said works quite well, starting with `import {} from Module` and going from there. Again, this is dependent upon the IDE. When a module only exports one thing, you are responsible for the naming of that variable.

Happy Coding!