# Why not have `import module-name.export1` in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

What is the design limitation behind the ES6 import statement syntax?

```js
import { export1 } from "module-name";
```

as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Why not have

```js
import module-name.export1
```

If somehow having the 'import' keyword in the first place is so important, why not use it like that?

For comparison consider several other popular languages:

- Java : `import package.subpackage.ClassName;`
- Python : `from module import SomeClass`
- C#: `using System.Text;`

From left to right: *broadScope -> module -> particularItem*.
While in ES6, it goes backwards: *particularItem <- module*

How is it better to first write the `export1`, then the `module-name`?
How is that more optimal than `import module-name.export`?

Comment: You better ask this [TC-39](https://tc39.es/), we can only speculate the reasons behind the design.

Comment: If you’re asking why it’s not `from moduleName import { exportName }` in JS, see https://es.discourse.group/t/from-module-import-x/285

Comment: See also [Is there `from <module> import <class>` syntax in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63428001/1048572), Reddit: [Why is JS ES6 import syntax designed with such incompetence?](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/81clf5/rant_why_is_js_es6_import_syntax_designed_with/), blogposts [Typing import statements more quickly](https://2ality.com/2017/08/typing-import-statements.html) and [The Module Import in JavaScript Has a Drawback](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-import-module-drawback/), or [this TypeScript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2371)

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar please answer now

Answer (score -2):

I am not one of them - maintainers. But, here's a straightforward answer:

You know how linking to a folder work?

```
'./project/dir'
```

We use similar when linking to image, etc. It's a standard of HTML. And the ES6 is also a part of HTML5 (HTML, JavaScript, CSS). And thus, it follows to import modules from the folders specifying the path.

```
import defaultExport from '../path'
import { namedExport } from '../node_modules/package'
```

Like we define a variable to use:

```
// define myVar at first hand and declare it's value at second hand
const myVar = 10
console.log(myVar)
// But not
// 10 = const myVar
// console.log(10) // myVar
```

Following the approach, we have the import statements:

```
import myVar from 'module' // value is extracted from module
import { myKeyVar } from 'package'
console.log(myVar, myKeyVar)
```

So, I cannot urge to have definition like:

```
from 'module' import myVar
```

And finally, there's no alternative way for this. So, we cannot say that this is the best approach or the worst approach. It's just a standard they follow to implement it.

Comment: _“And the ES6 is also a part of HTML5 (HTML, JavaScript, CSS)”_ — That isn’t true at all. The rest of the answer has nothing whatsoever to do with HTML.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650426/whats-the-difference-html5-vs-javascript

Comment: And I am talking about HTML5 standard not just html.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar That link doesn’t say that ES6 is part of HTML5. These two are two completely different specifications, technologies, and languages. Modules are part of ES6. Things like Canvas are part of HTML5. _“In reality \[HTML5\] has become an all encompassing buzzword for \[JavaScript\] and every web technology developed since HTML4”_ does **not** imply that ES6 (which isn’t equivalent to JavaScript) is _part of_ HTML5. _“And I am talking about HTML5”_ — I said that the question and the second part of your answer have nothing to with HTML. HTML includes HTML5 already.

Comment: I don't get your argument. How is "linking a folder in html" (or directory structures in general) related to import syntax for modules? And how does this answer the question why we are writing `import x from './path/to/module'` instead of `from './path/to/module' import x`?!