# JavaScript, ES6 import from

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

The syntax for import is:

```
import { something } from 'path/to/something';
import somethingElse from 'path/to/somethingElse';
```

Those example in case the are some export default or not.

But why are we Importing something before saying `from`?

Shouldn't be more logic to write:

```
from 'path/to/something' import { whatINeed }
```

Because IDE's and vscode by knowing first from where I'm going to import something, it could suggest me each exported const, function, etc, to pick what I need.

PS: Didn't know where to ask this.

Comment: See also [Why not have `import module-name.export1` in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63520227/why-not-have-import-module-name-export1-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

The suggested syntax that you would prefer is used in other languages, Python is an example.

If you already have your path defined after your `from`, autocomplete will still work when you are importing within `{}`.

The preference for whether or not `import` or `from` should come first is just a matter of syntactic preference.

This is also illustrated through common languages.

In English adjectives go BEFORE nouns whereas in French the adjectives go AFTER.

I am not expressing a preference, just providing an explanation for why it may be the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the matter of syntax...
I think that it's much more readable to have

```
import {object} from '../../path';
import {object123} from '../../somefolder/path/someMorePath';
import {object1} from './smallPath';
import {object13} from './smallPath/path/path/path/path';
```

In that case - every object is grouped on the left. One under another.
For me it's logical because the imported object/function/whatever is much more important than a path and it's natural (in most countries :)) to start reading from the left side.

That's just my opinion :)